# Windows Installer Service could not be accessed (even though it's running)

Tags: windows-xp, installer

Something is blocking me from installing msi's on Windows XP (professional).
The error message I'm getting is:

```
    The Windows Installer Service could not be accessed.
    This can occur if you are running Windows in safe mode, or if
    the Windows Installer is not correctly installed.
```

I'm logged in as Administrator.
I reregistered the executable (msiexec /RegServer). I started the service
manually and it started successfully.

What else could be blocking the msi's from accessing the Windows Installer service
on an Administrator account?

The windows version is XP Professinal, Service Pack 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the recommended steps to take to solve this issue.

1. Log on to your computer as an administrator.
2. Click *`Start`*, and then click *`Run`*.
3. In the Open box, type `cmd`, and then click *`OK`*.
4. At the command prompt, `typemsiexec.exe /unregister`, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. Type `msiexec /regserver`, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
6. Verify that the `SYSTEM` account has full control access permissions to the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` hive in the Windows registry. In some cases, you may also have to add Administrator accounts.

   1. Click *`Start`*, click *`Run`*, type `regedit` in the Open box, and then click *`OK`*.
   2. Click the following registry hive: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`
   3. On the *`Edit menu`*, click *`Permissions`*.
   4. If `SYSTEM` is not listed in the Group or user names list, click *`Add`*, make sure that the local computer name appears in the *`From this location`* box, type `System` in the *`Enter the object names to select`* box, click *`Check Names`*, and then click *`OK`*.
   5. Click `SYSTEM` in the *`Group or user names`* list, and then select the *`Full Control`* check box under *`Allow`* in the *`Permissions for SYSTEM`* box.
   6. Click *`Apply`*, click *`OK`*, and then quit the Registry Editor.
7. Restart the computer.

If the problem is not resolved, [repair Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315341) XP.

---

*This information was taken from the ["The Windows Installer Service Could Not Be Accessed" error message when you install a program in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315353/en-us)-article.*

Comment: I had a pc with exactly that problem, and unregistering/registering msiexec fixed it right up.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any virus or security software running?  Sometimes these programs will interrupt an install process to try and get in the middle of the operation.  This is to inspect the content that will eventually end up on your hard disk.  I would try to recycle your security software or disable it entirely for the duration of the install effort.