# Windows Installer Service could not be accessed

Tags: windows-7, windows-installer

Whenever I try to install a program I get the following error:

> The Windows Installer Service could not be accessed.  This can occur if the Windows Installer is not correctly installed.  Contact your support personnel for assistance.

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate - Version 6.1 (Build 7600).

I have tried the following solutions, to no avail:

1. Go to services.msc and start Windows Installer
   When I try that, I get the error message:

   > Windows could not start the Windows Installer Service on Local computer.  Error 5: Access is denied.

   When I tried as Admin, I could not even open services.msc. It said:

   > This function is not supported on this system.
2. Deleting a second msiexec.

   When I went to `C:\Windows\system32`, there was no second msiexec.
3. Modify Remote Procedure Call Service

   When I got to the Log On tab I was not able to choose Local System Account.
4. Reinstall Windows Installer Service by downloading MSIServer

   After I merged the two files nothing changed.
5. Install the latest Windows Installer version.

   I already have the latest version.
6. Run regedit. Navigate through `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE…SYSTEM…CURRENTCONTROLSET…SERVICES…MSIServer`. Then right click on `WOW64` and select “Modify.”

   When I got through the steps, there was no WOW64 for me to choose.

I do not know what else to try.

Comment: Did you read all the related links in this article?...http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2438651

Comment: Possible duplicate...http://superuser.com/questions/19182/windows-installer-service-could-not-be-accessed-even-though-its-running

Comment: I tried http://superuser.com/questions/19182/windows-installer-service-could-not-be-accessed-even-though-its-running and System already had full control.

Comment: I even tried system restore but I got the following errors:
Access is denied (0x80070005)
The parameter is incorrect (0x800700057)

Comment: In a slightly different situation I had great success with [the answer in *Can't install iTunes because Windows Installer Service could not be accessed*](http://superuser.com/questions/481664/cant-install-itunes-because-windows-installer-service-could-not-be-accessed/932283#932283).