# Windows Installer fails to install MSI file

Tags: windows-7, windows-installer

I am trying to install an MSI file on Windows 7, and I am getting the error message "There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor."

[image]

There's actually 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the MSI file, and both of them fail with the same error.

I tried the following things:

1) Checked services.msc and noticed the Windows Installer service was not running, so I started it, but the MSI file installation still failed with the same error.

2) Typed "msiexec /unreg" and "msiexec /regserver" from the command prompt, but the MSI file installation still failed with the same error.

3) Downloaded and ran [this Microsoft fix](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/program_install_and_uninstall), but it didn't detect any problems, and the MSI file installation still failed with the same error.

Re-installing Windows Installer doesn't seem to be an option, as it appears Microsoft does not offer a Windows Installer 5.0 download.

Any ideas?

Comment: Antivirus or the like?

Comment: @Mihai This computer's antivirus program tells me the last virus/malware/spyware/grayware was detected a few months ago, so I'm pretty sure it's not blocking any part of the installation.  I don't have permission to disable the antivirus.

Comment: Have you tried running the installer as administrator? Is the application compatible with the OS? Do you have the latest Windows Installer version?

Comment: @BigChris Yes I did try installing as Administrator, and the program is compatible with Windows 7.  I am running Windows Installer 5.0.7601.17514 (the latest version available from Microsoft is actually 4.5 - don't ask me why).  Also, I just tried installing another MSI program and it worked fine, so I'm not sure why this one doesn't work.

Comment: I suppose your copy of UScreenCapture is indeed the latest version (2.0.15)? Also, does an [older version](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/UScreenCapture/old-versions#download) install correctly?

Comment: Try it on another computer with win 7.It might be the antivirus.Or do you have EMET installed by any chance?

Comment: @BenjiWiebe Correct, I downloaded 2.0.15 from videohelp.com.

Comment: @BenjiWiebe I just tried installing 2.0.14 and it failed with the same error as well.

Comment: Also try re-downloading the installer and compare the md5 of it to what's advertised. You may have some corrupt installers. Try installing from a different account?

Comment: @Mihai EMET is not on this computer.

Comment: Also try the Windows Installer CleanUp utility.

Comment: Also try closing all open programs, copying `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp` to `Temp.old` and then deleting everything in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp`

Comment: @BigChris The MSI file is actually contained in a zip file that I downloaded from videohelp.com.  I used the "test" feature of a couple zipping programs and it tested fine, so it's not possible the MSI file was corrupted while downloading.  Also, according to this page http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301, the Windows Installer Cleanup Utility is no longer available.

Comment: Go to msconfig and do a selective startup but disable all non - Microsoft services. Once restarted in selective boot, try your installer.

Comment: You could also try step 2 [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_programs/error-1720-there-is-a-problem-with-this-windows/0b965fe8-2d16-498c-bb88-395911e13146)

Comment: Did you do "msiexec /unreg" and "msiexec /regserver" for both 32-bit and 64-bit as in [the answer to *Can't install iTunes because Windows Installer Service could not be accessed*](http://superuser.com/questions/481664/cant-install-itunes-because-windows-installer-service-could-not-be-accessed/932283#932283) (unregister and register in folders %windir%\system32 and %windir%\system64)? I had great success with this, albeit for problems with an installer for another application.

Answer (score 2):

Create a **verbose log file** for the installation and **flush each line to the log** (this means msiexec.exe writes the log continuously and immediately instead of in delayed batches - important when you are dealing with crashes which this error message seems to indicate):

```
msiexec.exe /I "C:\Test.msi" /QN /L*V! "C:\msilog.log"
```

Then open the log file and search for "[value 3](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/8/2/the-first-thing-i-do-with-an-msi-log/)" to find the right entry in the massive log file that will have been created (it is a verbose log file thanks to the /L*V switch).

Also see [**this answer on stackoverflow.com**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23945198/129130) for more information.