# Why don't any MSI (Windows Installer) installers work?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, installation, windows-installer

For quite some time already, I have not been able to install any applications that in any way use the Windows Installer (aka `msiexec`) which is most of the apps out there. I am not talking about some random specific program that does not install, it's ANY program.

All the installers say this:

[image: Setup Wizard ended prematurely]

The one I am using right now is: http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/F/F/CFF3A0B8-99D4-41A2-AE1A-496C08BEB904/WebPlatformInstaller_amd64_en-US.msi

As you can see, it is an official Microsoft download, so the package is not the problem.

Also, using [this SuperUser post](https://superuser.com/a/785367/300996) I ran `msiexec.exe /I "WebPlatformInstaller_amd64_en-US.msi" /QN /L*V! "C:\msilog.log"` and I got this log:

```
=== Verbose logging started: 3/28/2015  20:46:26  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.9600.00  Calling process: C:\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe ===
MSI (c) (0C:C4) [20:46:26:944]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (0C:C4) [20:46:26:994]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 7
MSI (c) (0C:C4) [20:46:27:034]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: WebPlatformInstaller_amd64_en-US.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine:  
MSI (c) (0C:C4) [20:46:27:062]: Client-side and UI is none or basic: Running entire install on the server.
MSI (c) (0C:C4) [20:46:27:086]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (0C:C4) [20:46:27:137]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (0C:C4) [20:46:27:166]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (0C:C4) [20:46:27:194]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (B8:30) [20:46:27:222]: Running installation inside multi-package transaction C:\Users\Maxwell\Downloads\WebPlatformInstaller_amd64_en-US.msi
MSI (s) (B8:30) [20:46:27:243]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (s) (B8:7C) [20:46:27:270]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
MSI (s) (B8:30) [20:46:27:295]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (B8:30) [20:46:27:318]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (B8:30) [20:46:27:345]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (B8:30) [20:46:27:369]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (B8:30) [20:46:27:395]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (B8:30) [20:46:27:419]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (0C:C4) [20:46:27:446]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (0C:C4) [20:46:27:470]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
=== Verbose logging stopped: 3/28/2015  20:46:27 ===
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening and most importantly, how to fix it.

System Info: 
OS: Windows 8.1
Architecture: x64

I don't have any actual anti-virus. Just the default Windows Defender or whatever they call it now.

EDIT: When I analyzed msiexec.exe using Process Explorer, I found that it tries to access a registry key that does not exist: (click to enlarge)
[image: Process Explorer]

Comment: Sounds like as a previous installation did not complete.

Comment: @harper: so... "most importantly, how to fix it." How do I force complete the previous install. Or cancel, or rollback, whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Try msicuu (Windows Installer CleanUp Utility) to remove a broken MSI install attempt
2. Go into services.msc and make sure the Windows Installer service is set to run "manual".  If running, stop it. Or use sc.exe command to stop it.
3. Instead of /QN try /qb! to see the progress, or just run the .msi package interactively.  It might show more detail.  Try something less complex like 7-zip.
4. Check the Windows event logs (application and system logs) and search for events right around the date/time of the failures.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It works. I killed the service and fixed it using msicuu. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

msiexec.exe only allows one MSI to modify the system at a time. From your log file it looks like your installs are failing soon after grabbing the msiexec mutex lock:

```
MSI (s) (B8:30) [20:46:27:243]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (s) (B8:7C) [20:46:27:270]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
```

Check that the msiexec.exe process is not running in TaskManager before you run your installer.

Comment: And if it is running, is the solution just to kill the process in TaskManager?  Is there any further cleanup required for the previous execution?  What if it isn't found running in TaskManager?

Comment: I did notice that even after closing the setup, the `msiexec` is still there, but even after I kill it, I get the same error when i try installing again.

Comment: As time passes, I am increasingly leaning toward this possibly being an un-finished install that is lying around somewhere, but I have no Idea where to check.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like installer fails to access registry key:

```
MSI (s) (B8:30) [20:46:27:369]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (B8:30) [20:46:27:395]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2
```

[Error 1402](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372835.aspx): `Could not open key: [2]. System error [3].`

Check permissions for that key. I don't have it on my PC, but here is the permissions for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer` (full-size on click):

[image: permissions for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer]

Also check if there any rollback scripts in that key, it could be the issue: [Weird rollback behavior in Windows Installer with .NET Framework setup](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2004/08/06/210300.aspx).

As a last resort one can monitor `msiexec.exe` with [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645), and see if there is any unusual errors.

Comment: See my edit. As you can see there the registry key that the article you linked to showed does not exist in the first place.