# Why do most of my installers fail to work?

Tags: windows, windows-10, installation, windows-installer

For a while, any installers which use the Windows installer in any way, all fail to install, with the error `The specified path 'C:\WINDOWS\Installer\Config.Msi\' is unavailable`.

[image]

The folder doesn't exist on my machine at all.
Other times, installers will throw in an error code. [image]

All the solutions I try to look for mention `C:\Config.Msi` and none of those have worked for me. As far as I remember, most of them deal with folder permissions.

I also found this [previous question/solution](https://superuser.com/questions/895255/why-dont-any-msi-windows-installer-installers-work), which did not work for me. Running msicuu just resulted in the exact same `'C:\WINDOWS\Installer\Config.Msi\' is unavailable` error message, this time showing error code 1314.

Following that up, I saw that msicuu has been replaced by [Program Install and Uninstall Troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/windows-fix-problems-that-block-programs-being-installed-or-removed), which also was not able to do anything for me. I tested on one program that fails to install updates. It suggested to uninstall the program, which it did successfully, and now I cannot reinstall it.

System info: Windows 10 x64, version 1909

Comment: Does the folder `C:\Windows\Installer` exist? If not did you try to create that folder?

Comment: It does exist, and it contains a lot of msp and msi files, and many folders with product codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in order:

1. In an Admin Command Prompt, run:
   `dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` followed by
   `SFC /SCANNOW`. When all complete, restart and test.
2. If option (1) fails, make a new, test Windows User Profile (Account). Log into the new Account and test. If a new Account works, you need to back up and create a new user Account for yourself.
3. If option 1 and 2 fail, run a Windows 10 Repair Install and see if that works.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run.
>
> This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

Restart when done and test.

Comment: I had to do option 3 to finally get my installers working again. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the update and that is good that Windows 10 Repair worked for you, and also that your User Profile is good and was not damaged.